# Add UIToolbar to UIViewController

Tags: iphone

How to add `UIToolbar` to the below `UIViewController`.

```
PageOneViewController *viewController = [[PageOneViewController alloc] init];

[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

[viewController release];
```

This `UIViewController` is the view of the `mainviewcontroller` and `UIToolbar` is in the `mainviewcontroller`. So basically when this view is loaded i want `UIToolbar` to load as well.

Can someone give me an idea

Comment: Have you tried dragging a UIToolbar into your view controller's view in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `UIToolbar` as a subview of the `PageOneViewController`:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[viewController addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
toolbar.frame = // Set this to position the toolbar correctly

[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```